# Conditional in <response> tag in VisualforcePage

Tags: visualforce, rendered, renderas, twilio

I'm newbie in Salesforce, and I am having a problem that I cant fix. I am using Twilio for making/receiving calls. I would like to put a conditional on my VFP depending on a variable that is set on the controller, to respond one thing or another.

The situation is the next one: 
The VisualForcePage:

```
    <!--(condition if the variable {!Number} == '1')-->  
    <Response>
        <Say>Hello</Say>                
    </Response>
    <-- end of the condition-->

    <!--(condition if the variable {!Number} == '2')-->
    <Response>
        <Say>GoodBye</Say>                
    </Response>     
    <-- end of the condition-->
```

And this is the controller:

```
public class myController{

    public String getNumber() {
        String Number = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('From');
        return Number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need apex:outputpanel and rendered condition to make it work.

```
<apex:outputpanel layout="none" rendered="{!Number == '1'}">
     <Response>
        <Say>Hello</Say>                
    </Response>
</apex:outputpanel>
<apex:outputpanel layout="none" rendered="{!Number == '2'}">
     <Response>
        <Say>GoodBye</Say>                
    </Response>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using one or more page divisions, such as `<apex:outputPanel>`, with a `rendered` attribute, which controls conditional rendering. Populate the `rendered` attribute with a Visualforce expression that evaluates to a boolean (and can reference controller properties) to determine on the server side whether or not it renders.

Note that any regions that have `rendered` evaluate to `false` are never sent to the client, so you can't dynamically rerender them. If you need that functionality, wrap them in an outer `outputPanel` that can be the target of the `rerender`.

Comment: thanks for the response David, I have thought to do that, but if my variable is a number, and there are more than 2 options? Is not a property like rendered as?
cheers

Comment: You can use as many conditionally rendered sections as necessary to render the correct view for each possible option, although with a large number of options this will quickly become unwieldy and may recommend a change in page architecture. There isn't really a Visualforce equivalent of a `case` statement.

Comment: Please edit your question with what you've tried and any error messages rather than using comment threads. Thanks.